# How to Request storage permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to call my class for checking storage permission

```
// check for permissions
    permissions.checkpermissions(getBaseContext());
```

but the problem is, It is not letting me implement this in a class I am getting the following errors-

"The method onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) of type permissions must override or implement a supertype method"

"The method requestPermissions(String[], int) is undefined for the type permissions"

here is my code-

```
public class permissions {

public static void checkpermissions(Context context) {
    // Check if we're running on Android 6.0 or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(context)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 2909);
        } else {
            // continue with your code
        }
    } else {
        // continue with your code
    }
    // **check if app has permission 1**//

}

// **check if app has permission 2**//
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 2909: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
        } else {
            Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
        }
        return;
    }
    }
}

// **check if app has permission 2**//
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `requestPermissions()` or override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on arbitrary classes. Those are on `Activity`. You already have an `Activity`. Get rid of this `permissions` class and move your permission-related logic to your `Activity`.

Or, use one of [many libraries that help you implement runtime permissions](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=runtime%20permissions).

Comment: I tried implementing this in my main activity first, it worked perfectly, but It made my app start with a weird animation (fade out) I think it is normally fade in. and I always have two instances of my app when I have this implemented.